# Should classes that are passed references to IDisposable objects be IDisposable as well and set them to null when disposed?

Tags: c#, reference, null, idisposable

I think the question says it all.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a pretty odd meaning of "holding a reference" then. So your class is passed a reference (e.g. in the constructor) but doesn't take any responsibility for clean-up?

Comment: Valuable edit. Makes quite a difference.

Comment: @Trap: better if you give a simplified example here.

Comment: @Jon: That's it. Sorry if my English sound odd at times, I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They should implement `IDisposable` if the object *owns* that resource. There's generally no need to set things to null, although it does no harm.

If you *don't* own the resource, then clearly you shouldn't dispose of it, and you don't need to implement `IDisposable`. In my experience it's relatively rare that I have a member variable for a disposable resource which I don't own in my classes though...

Comment: Jon, in the WinForms world components often 'link' to each other w/o owning something (DataSource). Whether that is such a good pattern is something else.

Comment: @Henk: That's true. It's very context-dependent, obviously :)

Answer (score 3):

"Holding a reference" is not the real criterium. When an object logically 'owns' an IDiposable object then Yes, it should implement IDisposable to call Dispose for all owned Disposable objects.
But it should not implement a destructor (Finalizer) .

Answer (score 1):

Setting to null isn't necessary, but you *should* call `.Dispose()` on all of those objects from the parent class's `.Dispose()`.

**EDIT:** IF AND ONLY IF your class was responsible for creating those objects.

Comment: Only if that parent class is also responsible for creating the object. Cleaning up resources owned by other classes seems like a risky design to me.

Answer (score 0):

This a good practice yes. When the dispose of such a class is called, it's a good idea to call Dispose on all referenced objects as well.

Comment: It's not the same setting IDisposable references to null and calling Dispose on them, you would never want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they should if the reference is owned by the class, FxCop / MS code analysis even have a [check](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182172.aspx) for it.

Answer (score 0):

If your class creates the disposable object then your class is responsible for cleaning them up. Since your class won't know when to cleanup unless something tells it to (i don't count destructors) it is the easiest way to make your class implement IDisposable.

If your class uses, but does not create, disposable objects then you should leave cleaning up to the creator of those objects.

Comment: The Creator is often, but not always the Owner.

Comment: Ownership is not strictly determined as the creator. `StreamReader` takes a `Stream` (created elsewhere) in its constructor, but it logically owns the stream and `StreamReader.Dispose()` calls `Stream.Dispose()`.